# Reagent Template with Datomic dependency causes wrong behavior in the leiningen REPL

Tags: clojure, leiningen, datomic, reagent, cursive

I started a new Reagent project with `lein new reagent sample-proj` (you can use the latest to reproduce the problem). After a while I added the client-dependency for datomic (I had to exclude `jetty-http`, since it conflicted with `ring-server`).

```
[com.datomic/clj-client "0.8.606"
  :exclusions [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http]
]
```

Then I realized that in the `lein repl` you cannot run the server any more with `(start-server)`. On `localhost:3000` you just get a `ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED`. There are no message in the console.

Even weirder is that, if I start the nREPL from within Cursive, everything works just fine.

Does anybody know what is going on here. I'm lost with this, since in cursive REPL figwhweel's `app.js` is not found. My `project.clj` is this:
https://gist.github.com/frickm/4cfdba9ae812a909dfe8d5719c94718e.

thanks in advance
fricke

Comment: Found this out of shear luck: was getting a socket refused connection when attempting to connect to nREPL started inside a boot-clj pod, but worked when doing `boot repl` and starting things manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is a further dependency conflict? I can reproduce the issue with the steps that you mentioned.

You might try additional exclusions (as seen in the [Maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datomic/clj-client/0.8.606)):

```
[com.datomic/clj-client "0.8.606" :exclusions
   [org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-http org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util
    org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-client]]
```

Comment: I think it is weird that it worked. When you exclude the jetty-client dependency it's not even loaded any more. But without excluding it, you get a class-load-error for org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ExecutionStrategy$Producer. Anyway, thanks a lot though I'm using the peer-library now and will swap later.

Comment: Can someone explain how it is possible for a library like the Datomic Client LIbrary to invisibly override how sockets/nREPL work with no warning?